# Loding a 3D Model using ThreeJS / GLTF loader on my live (static?) website?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, three.js, gltf

I have worked previously on a simple ThreeJS / GLTF loader project that I hosted on a remote server using Nodejs and npm run start.

However, now I want to load a 3D model on my live webpage. Static website? The idea is to have a div or a frame where users can orbit around the model.
I am looking online and I can't seem to find the right resources on how to do that. I tried some options but I get strange errors and some do ruin my existing file structure or file. My website is hosted on github using custom domain from godaddy.

I have html, css and javascripts in my files already for other feature (other than the GLTF loader) but not threejs.

Anyone could guide on how to start this. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try model-viewer?  https://modelviewer.dev/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It looks simpler and easier to implement. I just tried it, however, I am facing a problem. The model is not loading, and I believe that is due to "internet permission"? I am trying to figure out what I should add to allow for model loading, but seems like it is still not working.
I am using github to host my custom domain (from godaddy) - if that is something that could cause some issues.

Comment: Try "downloading" your glTF from your own server, at the URL where you think it should be available, to see if the server is giving an error instead of the file.  If you get a specific error that you don't understand, you might be able to post a new question here focused on that error.

Comment: If you're having problems downloading due to "internet permission", then make sure both your website and GLTF asset are being hosted on the same domain. If your website is www.myBeautifulWebsite.net then the GLTF should also be hosted on www.myBeautifulWebsite.net

Comment: I added my model (origami.glb) to my main folder, and then went to www.myBeautifulWebsite.net/origami.glb - it downloaded fine. Which means the problem is not the internet permission? Since both the website files and model are in the same github folder?